# Running 'npm audit fix --force' downgrades react-scripts

Tags: node.js, package.json, npm-audit, npm-vulnerabilities, dependency-tree

I have a huge problem with my project in React. 
I'm trying to update the libraries on my project, but something goes
wrong.

This is the `package.json`.
Note that the `react-scripts` version is set to `"^4.0.3"`.

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "v14.16.0",
    "npm": ">=7.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cookie-session": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-socket.io-session": "^1.3.5",
    "heroku-ssl-redirect": "0.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.17",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.18",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "path-parser": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "sendgrid": "^5.2.3",
    "socket.io": "^3.1.1",
    "stripe": "^8.137.0"
  }
}
```

And below is the response after running `npm audit fix --force`,
which downgrades the `react-scripts` package to 1.1.5.
This causes even more vulnerabilities. 
I have no idea how to solve this.
I already tried cleaning the npm cache, removing the `node_modules`
folder, and removing the `package-lock.json`.

```
# npm audit report

browserslist  4.0.0 - 4.16.4
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1747
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/browserslist
  react-dev-utils  >=6.0.0-next.03604a46
  Depends on vulnerable versions of browserslist
  node_modules/react-dev-utils
    react-scripts  1.0.7-alpha.60ae2b6d || >=1.0.8
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts

dns-packet  <5.2.2
Severity: high
Memory Exposure - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1745
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/dns-packet
  multicast-dns  6.0.0 - 7.2.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of dns-packet
  node_modules/multicast-dns
    bonjour  >=3.3.1
    Depends on vulnerable versions of multicast-dns
    node_modules/bonjour
      webpack-dev-server  >=2.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of bonjour
      node_modules/webpack-dev-server
        @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin  >=0.3.1
        Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
        node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
          react-scripts  1.0.7-alpha.60ae2b6d || >=1.0.8
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
          Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
          Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
          node_modules/react-scripts

postcss  7.0.0 - 8.2.9
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/postcss
node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/postcss
  autoprefixer  9.0.0 - 9.8.6
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/autoprefixer
  css-blank-pseudo  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-blank-pseudo
    postcss-preset-env  >=6.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-blank-pseudo
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-prefers-color-scheme
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-color-gray
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-double-position-gradients
    node_modules/postcss-preset-env
  css-declaration-sorter  4.0.0 - 5.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-declaration-sorter
  css-has-pseudo  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-has-pseudo
  css-loader  2.0.0 - 4.3.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-loader
    react-scripts  1.0.7-alpha.60ae2b6d || >=1.0.8
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts
  css-prefers-color-scheme  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-prefers-color-scheme
  cssnano  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.1.1 - 4.1.11
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/cssnano
    optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin  3.2.1 || 5.0.2 - 5.0.6
    Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano
    node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
  cssnano-preset-default  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-util-raw-cache
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-reduce-initial
  node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
  cssnano-util-raw-cache  >=4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/cssnano-util-raw-cache
  icss-utils  4.0.0 - 4.1.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/icss-utils
    postcss-modules-local-by-default  2.0.0 - 4.0.0-rc.4
    Depends on vulnerable versions of icss-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    node_modules/postcss-modules-local-by-default
    postcss-modules-values  2.0.0 - 4.0.0-rc.5
    Depends on vulnerable versions of icss-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    node_modules/postcss-modules-values
  postcss-attribute-case-insensitive  4.0.0 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-attribute-case-insensitive
  postcss-browser-comments  2.0.0 - 3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-browser-comments
    postcss-normalize  7.0.0 - 9.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-browser-comments
    node_modules/postcss-normalize
  postcss-calc  6.0.2 - 7.0.5
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-calc
  postcss-color-functional-notation  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-functional-notation
  postcss-color-gray  >=5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-gray
  postcss-color-hex-alpha  4.0.0 - 6.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-hex-alpha
  postcss-color-mod-function  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-mod-function
  postcss-color-rebeccapurple  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-rebeccapurple
  postcss-colormin  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-colormin
  postcss-convert-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-convert-values
  postcss-custom-media  7.0.0 - 7.0.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-media
  postcss-custom-properties  8.0.0 - 10.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-properties
  postcss-custom-selectors  5.0.0 - 5.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-selectors
  postcss-dir-pseudo-class  >=5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-dir-pseudo-class
  postcss-discard-comments  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-comments
  postcss-discard-duplicates  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-duplicates
  postcss-discard-empty  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-empty
  postcss-discard-overridden  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-overridden
  postcss-double-position-gradients  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-double-position-gradients
  postcss-env-function  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-env-function
  postcss-flexbugs-fixes  4.0.0 - 4.2.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-flexbugs-fixes
  postcss-focus-visible  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-focus-visible
  postcss-focus-within  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-focus-within
  postcss-font-variant  4.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-font-variant
  postcss-gap-properties  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-gap-properties
  postcss-image-set-function  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-image-set-function
  postcss-initial  3.0.0 - 3.0.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-initial
  postcss-lab-function  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-lab-function
  postcss-loader  3.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-loader
  postcss-logical  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-logical
  postcss-media-minmax  4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-media-minmax
  postcss-merge-longhand  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.6 - 4.0.11
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-merge-longhand
  postcss-merge-rules  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-merge-rules
  postcss-minify-font-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-font-values
  postcss-minify-gradients  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-gradients
  postcss-minify-params  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-params
  postcss-minify-selectors  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-selectors
  postcss-modules-extract-imports  2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-extract-imports
  postcss-modules-scope  2.0.0 - 2.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-scope
  postcss-nesting  7.0.0 - 7.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-nesting
  postcss-normalize-charset  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-charset
  postcss-normalize-display-values  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-display-values
  postcss-normalize-positions  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-positions
  postcss-normalize-repeat-style  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-repeat-style
  postcss-normalize-string  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-string
  postcss-normalize-timing-functions  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-timing-functions
  postcss-normalize-unicode  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-unicode
  postcss-normalize-url  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-url
  postcss-normalize-whitespace  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-whitespace
  postcss-ordered-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.1.1 - 4.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-ordered-values
  postcss-overflow-shorthand  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-overflow-shorthand
  postcss-page-break  2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-page-break
  postcss-place  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-place
  postcss-pseudo-class-any-link  >=6.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-pseudo-class-any-link
  postcss-reduce-initial  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-initial
  postcss-reduce-transforms  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-transforms
  postcss-replace-overflow-wrap  3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-replace-overflow-wrap
  postcss-selector-matches  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-matches
  postcss-selector-not  4.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-not
  postcss-svgo  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-svgo
  postcss-unique-selectors  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-unique-selectors
  resolve-url-loader  3.0.0-alpha.1 - 4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/resolve-url-loader
  stylehacks  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/stylehacks

87 vulnerabilities (81 moderate, 6 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

Comment: Partial cause: Seems like a react-scripts issue (needs update dns-packet) which is currently being looked at here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few developers are now slowly getting this hopefully temporary problem when they update their projects.

For example:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11012

Recommendation is to leave this on the todo list, and wait a few days while the package developers fix this (at least for the packages that already have been notified)

Then run `audit fix` again

In the meantime, one error in particular the 'high' severity one...

```
dns-packet  <5.2.2
Severity: high
Memory Exposure - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1745
```

https://npmjs.com/advisories/1745

Would be an problem if the react-application is running in dev mode on a public network e.g. running a server in dev mode on heroku via `npm run start` to the whole world (a BAD idea, consider searching how to deploy in react application in production mode, there are a few methods).

If you are @home, on a local network, you should be ok.

If you are on public wifi - just don't for now

Answer (score 18):

One of the create-react-app maintainers has announced that they cannot fix this as the vulnerabilities affect transitive dependencies, and that it should not matter.

The reasoning is that the `npm audit` feature was built with Node apps in mind, not build tools. Vulnerabilities in the dependencies should (in most cases) not translate to vulnerabilities in the static web app produced by create-react-app.

A possible workaround is to move `react-scripts` to the `devDependencies` section in your `package.json` and use `npm audit --production` to audit your dependencies.

Source: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174

Comment: This is a good workaround .. except that I need `react-scripts` to build, so that has to be installed in production, e.g., on Heroku.

Answer (score 5):

#### 0. Reproducing your findings

Thanks for including the `package.json` in your question! 
By doing that, anyone can [reproduce your findings](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

I ran [`npm install npm@latest -g`](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities),
and then `npm --version`, which responded `9.6.4`.

In an empty directory, I added your `package.json`,
then ran `npm install`, then `npm audit`.

The response was
`34 vulnerabilities (1 low, 4 moderate, 20 high, 9 critical)`.

In the resulting [NPM audit security report](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-audit-reports),
<sup>1</sup> 
the packages `ejs`, `immer`, `loader-utils`, and `shell-quote`
have *critical* vulnerabilities.

The packages `ansi-html`, `glob-parent`, `minimatch`, `node-forge`,
and `nth-check` are reported to have *high* vulnerabilities.

The packages `browserslist`, `engine.io`, and `passport`, have
*moderate* vulnerabilities.

Here is a screenshot of a part of the audit report, displaying a few
of the mentioned vulnerabilities.

[image: A part of the audit report, severity: critical and high]

### 1. How to fix all your vulnerabilities

The reason vulnerabilities are reported is that some packages are too
old to have been corrected. 
Take the package `ejs` as an example.
The `package.json` does *not directly* depend on `ejs`. 
The dependency is *indirect*, which means that `ejs` occurs somewhere
deeper in the dependency tree.
To find out *where* exactly, I ran `npm ls ejs` :

```
$ npm ls ejs
server@1.1.0 …
`-- react-scripts@4.0.3
  `-- workbox-webpack-plugin@5.1.4
    `-- workbox-build@5.1.4
      `-- @surma/rollup-plugin-off-main-thread@1.4.2
        `-- ejs@2.7.4
```

[image: The package ejs depends indirectly on react-scripts]

The remedy is to *force* the use of a newer version of `ejs`. 
To find the *latest* version of `ejs`, I ran
`npm view ejs | grep latest` :
<sup>2</sup>

```
$ npm view ejs | grep latest
latest: 3.1.9
```

[image: 'npm view ejs' - the latest version is 3.1.9]

By repeating this for all the above-mentioned packages that were
found to be vulnerable, the latest version of each such package may
be found.

##### [In December 2021, the Node package manager introduced the *overrides* clause](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/changelog#v830-2021-12-09).

The [*overrides*](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) functionality is designed to do exactly what I want.
In short, insert the following chunk of code right after
the second-last closing curly brace in `package.json` :

```
,
  "overrides": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "immer": "^9.0.21",
    "loader-utils": "^3.2.1",
    "shell-quote": "^1.8.0",
    "ansi-html": "^0.0.9",
    "glob-parent": "^6.0.2",
    "minimatch": "^8.0.2",
    "node-forge": "^1.3.1",
    "nth-check": "^2.1.1",
    "browserslist": "^4.21.5",
    "engine.io": "^6.4.1",
    "passport": "^0.6.0"
  }
```

When I did that, and then ran `npm install`, I got an `EOVERRIDE`
error :

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code EOVERRIDE
npm ERR! Override for passport@^0.4.1 conflicts with direct dependency
```

[image: npm ERR! code EOVERRIDE]

The error message tells what the problem is – there is a
*direct* dependency on passport@^0.4.1. 
At the same time, I'm asking npm to *override* the package `passport`
with version ^0.6.0. 
[This is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75253708).

The solution is to do the versioning *by reference*:
[`"passport": "$passport"`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides). 
But the version in `"passport": "^0.4.1"` can
*not* be tolerated 
– it needs to be upgraded to `"passport": "^0.6.0`.
<sup>3</sup>

When I now ran `npm install`, I got the wanted message:
`found 0 vulnerabilities`.

[image: Finally, 'found 0 vulnerabilities']

### 2. Reasons to refrain from the `--force` flag

First of all, a plain `npm audit` command (*without* `fix`) neither
affects `package.json`, nor `package-lock.json` (the *lock* file).

Secondly, `npm audit fix` (*without* the `--force` flag) also
*does not affect* `package.json`. 
However, It *does modify* `package-lock.json`. 
Running `npm audit fix` a *second* time does *not alter*
`package-lock.json` *again*.

All of the above is radically different once you add the `--force`
flag. 
In general, `npm audit fix --force` will modify *both* `package.json`
and `package-lock.json`. 
This is because that command will *always* try to fix things – as long
as there are vulnerabilities.

The *first* time I run `npm audit fix --force` on your `package.json`,
three packages are *upgraded* : 
`passport` from ^0.4.1 to ^0.6.0,
`react-scripts` from ^4.0.3 to ^5.0.1, 
and `socket.io` from ^3.1.1 to ^4.6.1.
<sup>4</sup>

By contrast, the *second* time I run `npm audit fix --force`, the
`react-scripts` package is *downgraded* from ^5.0.1 to ^2.1.3.
This, of course, is exactly what you reported. 
The reason – as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68147331) – is that the
second time `npm audit fix --force` runs, the
[package manager](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/an-introduction-to-the-npm-package-manager) detects that there are vulnerabilities.
And to fix those vulnerabilities – since the latest version of
`react-scripts` (5.0.1) is already installed – it *downgrades* in an
attempt to adjust to other packages potentially being older.

I think it would make more sense if the `--force` flag would *never*
downgrade, but the designers of [NPM](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/an-introduction-to-the-npm-package-manager) apparently think
differently.

To get back to version ^5.0.1 of `react-scripts`, you can run
`npm audit fix --force` a *third* time.
– ***Or*** – you can refrain from ever using `--force`
in the first place.

If you still decide to use `--force`, at least do yourself
the favor of saving a copy of `package.json`, as there is no way
to get it back once you've applied the `--force` flag.

### 3. Some more thoughts on your `package.json`

##### 3. a. Exact version of Node.js?

I noticed that in your `package.json`, you set the version of Node.js
to be exactly 14.16.0. 
I haven't seen this before, but maybe you have a good reason to do so?

Your `package.json` works fine on my current version, 18.14.2. 
But I do get a warning saying *Unsupported engine* – every time I run
`npm install`.

##### 3. b. Caret in the versioning of `react-scripts`

I noticed that you've set the version of `react-scripts` as
`"^4.0.3"`. 
This is *not recommended* by the author of the package, who states : 
[*It is pretty risky to use carets at the react-scripts level because
it's an integration package*](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174#issuecomment-873432520).

##### 3. c. Many *direct* dependencies are also *indirect* dependencies

I noticed that many of the direct dependencies in your
`package.json` are already included in the dependency tree as
*indirect* dependencies.
I think it is better not to do this.

One such example is the `body-parser` package :

```
$ npm ls body-parser
server@1.1.0 …
+-- body-parser@1.20.2
`-- express@4.18.2
  `-- body-parser@1.20.1
```

[image: Dependencies of body-parser]

Since `body-parser` is already in the dependency tree (via
`express`), you might as well remove it from
`package.json` – as a *direct* dependency.

Other direct dependencies, that are already included indirectly, are
`cookie-parser`, `cors`, `express`, `lodash`, `moment`, and `mongodb`.

##### 3. d. A proposed `package.json`

After incorporating the changes I've hinted about in the preceding
subsections, here is a suggestion for an adjusted `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=7.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cookie-session": "^1.4.0",
    "express-socket.io-session": "^1.3.5",
    "heroku-ssl-redirect": "0.0.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.17",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.18",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "path-parser": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "sendgrid": "^5.2.3",
    "socket.io": "^3.1.1",
    "stripe": "^8.137.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "immer": "^9.0.21",
    "loader-utils": "^3.2.1",
    "shell-quote": "^1.8.0",
    "ansi-html": "^0.0.9",
    "glob-parent": "^6.0.2",
    "minimatch": "^8.0.2",
    "node-forge": "^1.3.1",
    "nth-check": "^2.1.1",
    "browserslist": "^4.21.5",
    "engine.io": "^6.4.1"
  }
}
```

### References

- [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- [Auditing package dependencies for security vulnerabilities](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities)
- [NPM audit security report](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-audit-reports)
- [The `overrides` functionality was introduced in npm v8.3.0.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/changelog#v830-2021-12-09)
- [The `overrides` version specification must match exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75253708)
- [Recommended: define the override version as a reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides)
- [Version history of `react-scripts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts?activeTab=versions)
- [`npm audit fix --force` may end up in a cycling loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68147331)
- [An introduction to the NPM package manager](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/an-introduction-to-the-npm-package-manager)
- [It's pretty risky to use carets for `react-scripts`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174#issuecomment-873432520)

---

<sup>1</sup>
As may be noted, the vulnerabilities in your audit report are vastly
different from the ones in mine.
This is to be expected as your NPM version is 7.6.0, whereas mine is
9.6.4.
Even more important is probably the 22 months time that has passed
since you posted your question.
This has given time to discover a lot more vulnerabilities.

<sup>2</sup>
On Windows, you can leave out the last part, and just run
`npm view ejs`.

<sup>3</sup>
In this case, the `passport` package might as well be removed from the
`overrides` clause altogether. Why? 
– Because there are *no indirect dependencies* on `passport`.
Running `npm ls passport` reveals that the *direct* dependency on
`passport` is the *only* dependency.
Thus, merely updating the `passport` version to ^0.6.0 is sufficient.

<sup>4</sup>
It makes perfect sense that it *downgraded* when you asked the
question, but *upgrades* now that I try to replicate. 
– At the time when you asked the question,
[version 4.0.3 was presumably the *latest* version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts?activeTab=versions),
but now when I run `npm audit fix --force`, it *upgrades* from the
now old version 4.0.3 to the *now* latest version 5.0.1.

Comment: Very nice explanation and solution, would mark this as the answer of the question!