# npm audit fix --force never able to avoid vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, npm-audit

I'm stuck in a situation where I've either got 22 vulnerabilities or 47. I can run `npm audit fix` but I'm always suggested to run the `--force` switch in order to actually perform an upgrade. From there I can either upgrade and get 22 vulns and then I perform the `--force` again and get 47 vulns, this cycle continues forever. What's the best way out, just leave the packages the way they are?

my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

When I try `npm --audit fix` in one situation:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: type-fest@0.21.3
npm ERR! node_modules/type-fest
npm ERR!   type-fest@"^0.21.3" from ansi-escapes@4.3.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/ansi-escapes
npm ERR!     ansi-escapes@"^4.2.1" from @jest/core@26.6.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@jest/core
npm ERR!       @jest/core@"^26.6.0" from jest@26.6.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/jest
npm ERR!         peer jest@"^26.0.0" from jest-watch-typeahead@0.6.1
npm ERR!         node_modules/jest-watch-typeahead
npm ERR!         1 more (react-scripts)
npm ERR!       1 more (jest-cli)
npm ERR!     ansi-escapes@"^4.3.1" from jest-watch-typeahead@0.6.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/jest-watch-typeahead
npm ERR!       jest-watch-typeahead@"0.6.1" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!         react-scripts@"^4.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     2 more (jest-watcher, terminal-link)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional type-fest@"^0.13.1" from @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.4.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!   @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@"0.4.3" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"^4.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

And then when I run it after another `--force`

```
# npm audit report

braces  <2.3.1
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/786
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/anymatch/node_modules/braces
node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/braces
node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/braces
node_modules/jest-message-util/node_modules/braces
node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/braces
node_modules/test-exclude/node_modules/braces
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/http-proxy-middleware/node_modules/braces
  micromatch  0.2.0 - 2.3.11
  Depends on vulnerable versions of braces
  Depends on vulnerable versions of parse-glob
  node_modules/anymatch/node_modules/micromatch
  node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/micromatch
  node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/micromatch
  node_modules/jest-message-util/node_modules/micromatch
  node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/micromatch
  node_modules/test-exclude/node_modules/micromatch
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/http-proxy-middleware/node_modules/micromatch
    anymatch  1.2.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    node_modules/anymatch
      sane  1.0.4 - 4.0.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of anymatch
      Depends on vulnerable versions of exec-sh
      node_modules/sane
        jest-haste-map  16.1.0-alpha.691b0e22 - 24.0.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
        Depends on vulnerable versions of sane
        node_modules/jest-haste-map
          jest-cli  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d || 12.1.2-alpha.6230044c - 24.8.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-jasmine2
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
          Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
          Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
          node_modules/jest-cli
            jest  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
            Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-cli
            node_modules/jest
              react-scripts  0.1.0 - 2.1.8
              Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
              Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
              Depends on vulnerable versions of file-loader
              Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
              Depends on vulnerable versions of sw-precache-webpack-plugin
              Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
              Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
              node_modules/react-scripts
          jest-runtime  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d - 24.8.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
          Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
          Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
          Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
          node_modules/jest-runtime
    http-proxy-middleware  0.3.0 - 0.17.4
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/http-proxy-middleware
      webpack-dev-server  <=3.11.2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
      Depends on vulnerable versions of http-proxy-middleware
      Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
      Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
      node_modules/webpack-dev-server
    jest-message-util  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 23.1.0 || 23.4.0 - 24.0.0-alpha.16
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    node_modules/jest-message-util
      jest-jasmine2  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-matchers
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
      node_modules/jest-jasmine2
        jest-config  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-jasmine2
        node_modules/jest-config
      jest-matchers  >=18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
      node_modules/jest-matchers
      jest-util  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
      node_modules/jest-util
        jest-environment-jsdom  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
        node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom
        jest-environment-node  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
        node_modules/jest-environment-node
        jest-snapshot  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 21.0.0-beta.1
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
        node_modules/jest-snapshot
    test-exclude  <=4.2.3
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    node_modules/test-exclude
      babel-plugin-istanbul  <=5.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of test-exclude
      node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul
        babel-jest  14.2.0-alpha.ca8bfb6e - 24.0.0-alpha.16
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
        node_modules/babel-jest

glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: moderate
Regular expression denial of service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1751
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/glob-base/node_modules/glob-parent
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar
    webpack-dev-server  <=3.11.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    Depends on vulnerable versions of http-proxy-middleware
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
    node_modules/webpack-dev-server
      react-scripts  0.1.0 - 2.1.8
      Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
      Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
      Depends on vulnerable versions of file-loader
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
      Depends on vulnerable versions of sw-precache-webpack-plugin
      Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
      Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
      node_modules/react-scripts
  glob-base  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/glob-base
    parse-glob  >=2.1.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-base
    node_modules/parse-glob
      micromatch  0.2.0 - 2.3.11
      Depends on vulnerable versions of braces
      Depends on vulnerable versions of parse-glob
      node_modules/anymatch/node_modules/micromatch
      node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/micromatch
      node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/micromatch
      node_modules/jest-message-util/node_modules/micromatch
      node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/micromatch
      node_modules/test-exclude/node_modules/micromatch
      node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/http-proxy-middleware/node_modules/micromatch
        anymatch  1.2.0 - 1.3.2
        Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
        node_modules/anymatch
          sane  1.0.4 - 4.0.1
          Depends on vulnerable versions of anymatch
          Depends on vulnerable versions of exec-sh
          node_modules/sane
            jest-haste-map  16.1.0-alpha.691b0e22 - 24.0.0
            Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
            Depends on vulnerable versions of sane
            node_modules/jest-haste-map
              jest-cli  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d || 12.1.2-alpha.6230044c - 24.8.0
              Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
              Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-jasmine2
              Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
              Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
              Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
              Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
              node_modules/jest-cli
                jest  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
                Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-cli
                node_modules/jest
              jest-runtime  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d - 24.8.0
              Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
              Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
              Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
              Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
              Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
              Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
              node_modules/jest-runtime
        http-proxy-middleware  0.3.0 - 0.17.4
        Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
        node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/http-proxy-middleware
        jest-message-util  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 23.1.0 || 23.4.0 - 24.0.0-alpha.16
        Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
        node_modules/jest-message-util
          jest-jasmine2  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-matchers
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
          node_modules/jest-jasmine2
            jest-config  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
            Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-jasmine2
            node_modules/jest-config
          jest-matchers  >=18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
          node_modules/jest-matchers
          jest-util  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
          node_modules/jest-util
            jest-environment-jsdom  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0
            Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
            node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom
            jest-environment-node  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0
            Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
            node_modules/jest-environment-node
            jest-snapshot  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 21.0.0-beta.1
            Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
            node_modules/jest-snapshot
        test-exclude  <=4.2.3
        Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
        node_modules/test-exclude
          babel-plugin-istanbul  <=5.0.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of test-exclude
          node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul
            babel-jest  14.2.0-alpha.ca8bfb6e - 24.0.0-alpha.16
            Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
            node_modules/babel-jest

js-yaml  <=3.13.0
Severity: high
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/788
Code Injection - https://npmjs.com/advisories/813
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/js-yaml
  svgo  0.4.2 - 1.0.5
  Depends on vulnerable versions of js-yaml
  node_modules/svgo
    postcss-svgo  <=2.1.6
    Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
    node_modules/postcss-svgo
      cssnano  <=3.10.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-url
      Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-svgo
      node_modules/cssnano
        css-loader  0.15.0 - 0.28.11
        Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano
        node_modules/css-loader
          react-scripts  0.1.0 - 2.1.8
          Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
          Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
          Depends on vulnerable versions of file-loader
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
          Depends on vulnerable versions of sw-precache-webpack-plugin
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
          node_modules/react-scripts

mem  <4.0.0
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1084
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/mem
  os-locale  2.0.0 - 3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of mem
  node_modules/webpack/node_modules/os-locale
    yargs  4.0.0-alpha1 - 12.0.5 || 14.1.0 || 15.0.0 - 15.2.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of os-locale
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs-parser
    node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/yargs
    node_modules/webpack/node_modules/yargs
    node_modules/yargs
      jest-cli  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d || 12.1.2-alpha.6230044c - 24.8.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-jasmine2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
      Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
      Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
      node_modules/jest-cli
        jest  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-cli
        node_modules/jest
          react-scripts  0.1.0 - 2.1.8
          Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
          Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
          Depends on vulnerable versions of file-loader
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
          Depends on vulnerable versions of sw-precache-webpack-plugin
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
          node_modules/react-scripts
      jest-runtime  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d - 24.8.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
      Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
      Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
      Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
      node_modules/jest-runtime
      webpack  2.0.0-beta - 4.0.0-beta.3
      Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
      node_modules/webpack
        babel-loader  7.0.0-alpha.1 - 7.1.2 || 8.0.0-beta.0 - 8.0.0-beta.6
        Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
        node_modules/babel-loader
        extract-text-webpack-plugin  2.0.0-beta.0 - 3.0.2
        Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
        node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin
        file-loader  1.1.1 - 1.1.9
        Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
        node_modules/file-loader
        webpack-dev-server  <=3.11.2
        Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
        Depends on vulnerable versions of http-proxy-middleware
        Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
        Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
        node_modules/webpack-dev-server

merge  <2.1.1
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1666
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/merge
  exec-sh  <=0.3.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of merge
  node_modules/exec-sh
    sane  1.0.4 - 4.0.1
    Depends on vulnerable versions of anymatch
    Depends on vulnerable versions of exec-sh
    node_modules/sane
      jest-haste-map  16.1.0-alpha.691b0e22 - 24.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
      Depends on vulnerable versions of sane
      node_modules/jest-haste-map
        jest-cli  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d || 12.1.2-alpha.6230044c - 24.8.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-jasmine2
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
        Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
        Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
        node_modules/jest-cli
          jest  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-cli
          node_modules/jest
            react-scripts  0.1.0 - 2.1.8
            Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
            Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
            Depends on vulnerable versions of file-loader
            Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
            Depends on vulnerable versions of sw-precache-webpack-plugin
            Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
            Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
            node_modules/react-scripts
        jest-runtime  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d - 24.8.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
        Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
        Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
        node_modules/jest-runtime

normalize-url  <=4.5.0 || 5.0.0 - 5.3.0 || 6.0.0
Severity: high
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1755
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/normalize-url
  postcss-normalize-url  <=4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of normalize-url
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-url
    cssnano  <=3.10.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-url
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-svgo
    node_modules/cssnano
      css-loader  0.15.0 - 0.28.11
      Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano
      node_modules/css-loader
        react-scripts  0.1.0 - 2.1.8
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
        Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
        Depends on vulnerable versions of file-loader
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
        Depends on vulnerable versions of sw-precache-webpack-plugin
        Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
        Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
        node_modules/react-scripts

trim-newlines  <3.0.1 || =4.0.0
Severity: high
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1753
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/trim-newlines
  meow  3.4.0 - 5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of trim-newlines
  node_modules/meow
    sw-precache  >=4.2.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of meow
    node_modules/sw-precache
      sw-precache-webpack-plugin  >=0.8.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of sw-precache
      node_modules/sw-precache-webpack-plugin
        react-scripts  0.1.0 - 2.1.8
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
        Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
        Depends on vulnerable versions of file-loader
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
        Depends on vulnerable versions of sw-precache-webpack-plugin
        Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
        Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
        node_modules/react-scripts

webpack-dev-server  <=3.11.2
Severity: high
Missing Origin Validation - https://npmjs.com/advisories/725
Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
Depends on vulnerable versions of http-proxy-middleware
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/webpack-dev-server
  react-scripts  0.1.0 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
  Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
  Depends on vulnerable versions of file-loader
  Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
  Depends on vulnerable versions of sw-precache-webpack-plugin
  Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
  Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
  node_modules/react-scripts

yargs-parser  <=13.1.1 || 14.0.0 - 15.0.0 || 16.0.0 - 18.1.1
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1500
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/yargs-parser
node_modules/webpack/node_modules/yargs-parser
node_modules/yargs-parser
  yargs  4.0.0-alpha1 - 12.0.5 || 14.1.0 || 15.0.0 - 15.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of os-locale
  Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs-parser
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/yargs
  node_modules/webpack/node_modules/yargs
  node_modules/yargs
    jest-cli  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d || 12.1.2-alpha.6230044c - 24.8.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-jasmine2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
    node_modules/jest-cli
      jest  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-cli
      node_modules/jest
        react-scripts  0.1.0 - 2.1.8
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
        Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
        Depends on vulnerable versions of file-loader
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
        Depends on vulnerable versions of sw-precache-webpack-plugin
        Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
        Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
        node_modules/react-scripts
    jest-runtime  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d - 24.8.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
    Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
    node_modules/jest-runtime
    webpack  2.0.0-beta - 4.0.0-beta.3
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
    node_modules/webpack
      babel-loader  7.0.0-alpha.1 - 7.1.2 || 8.0.0-beta.0 - 8.0.0-beta.6
      Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
      node_modules/babel-loader
      extract-text-webpack-plugin  2.0.0-beta.0 - 3.0.2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
      node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin
      file-loader  1.1.1 - 1.1.9
      Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
      node_modules/file-loader
      webpack-dev-server  <=3.11.2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
      Depends on vulnerable versions of http-proxy-middleware
      Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
      Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
      node_modules/webpack-dev-server
```

Comment: stay with the vulnerabilities and wait till the packages fix them. then update ur packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in a loop because `react-scripts@1` has some vulnerable dependencies and `react-scripts@4` has different vulnerable dependencies, so you're bouncing back and forth between them.
The first time you run `npm audit fix --force`, you update to `react-scripts@4.x`, and when you run it again, it downgrades you to `react-scripts@1.x` to remove the vulnerable dependencies in the 4.x version.

As of this writing, if you run `npx create-react-app my-app`, you get `react-scripts@4` (and the warning about 22 vulnerabilities) so maybe run `npm audit fix --force` to get to that state, run your tests to make sure nothing broke, and go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts from time to time to check for a release that bumps the dependencies (and/or run `npm audit` from time to time without the `--force` to see if it updates it automatically).