# Getting 5 vulnerabilities (2 high 3 medium) when i run npx create-react-app my-app

Tags: reactjs

i am new to coding and wanted to start a new react project , however run i run `npx create-react-app my-app` its says 5 vulnerabilities found. I have tried running  `npm audit fix` but this just says it needs to be manually updated is. i just wanted to ask is these vulnerabilities are a big deal.

Below is what it says when i run `npm audit`. thanks in advance for your help

The errors include

```
High - denial of service 
package css-what

High- denial of service
package css-what

Moderate-Regular expression denial of service  
package glob-parent   

Moderate-Regular expression denial of service    
package glob-parent  

Moderate-Regular expression denial of service    
package browserslist
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm audit fix --force react script downgrade automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67693423/npm-audit-fix-force-react-script-downgrade-automatically)