# Vulnerabilities with create-react-app React Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Every time I create a react app with `npx create-react-app <AppName>`, I get:

```
96 vulnerabilities found - Packages audited: 1682
Severity: 65 Moderate | 30 High | 1 Critical
Node Version: v14.18.1
Npm: 7.20.5
React: ^17.0.2
```

When I use `npm audit fix` OR `npm audit fix --force`, these are the results:

```
68 vulnerabilities (21 moderate, 45 high, 2 critical)
47 vulnerabilities (12 low, 18 moderate, 15 high, 2 critical)
58 vulnerabilities (16 moderate, 40 high, 2 critical)
48 vulnerabilities (12 low, 18 moderate, 16 high, 2 critical)
58 vulnerabilities (16 moderate, 40 high, 2 critical)
```

Here is the audit detail: [Text File Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kg_EU57uRJkFRdBOK-8IEugfURUsftlO/view?usp=sharing) What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I was confused and thought I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm audit fix --force react script downgrade automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67693423/npm-audit-fix-force-react-script-downgrade-automatically)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an NPM Bug. See [here](https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/) for a longer explanation. You just need to put `react-scripts` in dev dependices like that

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
   },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
```

This issue has already been solved on GitHub. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174
If you really want to audit use `npm audit --production`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I fixed it. How about now?

Comment: This is a partial answer. The other half is adding --production flag when you npm audit. `$ npm audit --production`