# How to solve React CRA issues which comes with fresh installation?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

When i freshly install react application with React CRA method it shows me :

```
74 vulnerabilities (69 moderate, 5 high)
```

and when i run :

```
npm audit fix --force
```

it throws :

```
126 vulnerabilities (10 low, 78 moderate, 30 high, 8 critical)
```

Any help to fix these issues will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is the same case but, have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69576030/464538) ?

Comment: i have tried that as well but that doesn't fix my issue and neither the downvoting solved my issue either.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest version of CRA? Try `npx create-react-app@latest`. FYI none of these things are errors, nor should they stop you working with React.

Comment: @Philisonstrike i tried with your command but it still giving me 74 vulnerabilities (69 moderate, 5 high)... i think there is no way to fix these issues..!!

Comment: Like I said, this isn't going to stop you building your app. If you feel it's really important, raise an issue against [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues) but check first, somebody else has probably already reported it

Comment: Just ignore the audit warnings. See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174

Comment: Agree with @Philisonstrike that you should ignore the warnings, they came from dev dependencies anyway and only appear in build files. But to be safe you can make sure that they always came from CRA when you install something.