# npx create-react-app running with old version

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

The latest version `create-react-app` is `4.0.3` but when I run `npx create-react-app my-app` it uses version 1.5.2 and also doesn't run with templates. I don't have any global installation of it and have tried uninstalling it using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`.

My npm version is 7.21.1 and node version is 16.9.1

How can I make it work? Please help.

EDIT: There are 58 vulnerabilities while creating the app and this comes at the end -

```
A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.
```

The folder also doesn't have the `src` folder just the `node_modules` folder and `package.json` file.

While running `npm audit fix` I get this -

```
tar  <=4.4.17
Severity: high
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite on Windows via insufficient relative path sanitization - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5955-9wpr-37jh
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite via insufficient symlink protection due to directory cache poisoning using symbolic links - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9r2w-394v-53qc
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite due to insufficient absolute path sanitization - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3jfq-g458-7qm9
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite via insufficient symlink protection due to directory cache poisoning - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r628-mhmh-qjhw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/tar
  tar-pack  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of tar
  node_modules/tar-pack
    create-react-app  >=1.3.0-alpha.58689133
    Depends on vulnerable versions of tar-pack
    node_modules/create-react-app

3 high severity vulnerabilities
```

Comment: Have you tried `npx create-react-app@latest my-app`? Can you confirm that `npm view create-react-app` shows the correct version as `latest`?

Comment: @Thor84no No it doesn't work. Yes they both show the same version. I have updated the question to show what is coming

Comment: Very odd. And does `npx create-react-app --version` (with or without `@latest`) show `4.0.3`? I just tested it and for me it installs with `4.0.3` and templates. (This is on Ubuntu with node `14.8.0` and npm `6.14.7`).

Comment: @Thor84no `npx create-react-app --version` shows version `1.5.2`

Comment: And you get the same for `npx create-react-app@latest --version`?

Comment: @Thor84no Yes it shows `1.5.2` only

Comment: That's weird. Most likely you have `1.5.2` in your npm cache, but it shouldn't use that when using `@latest`. You could try removing your npm cache (`npm config get cache` tells you where it is).

Comment: @Thor84no No it didn't work. After doing that when I did `npx create-react-app --version` it showed `1.5.2` and when I did `npx create-react-app@latest --version` it first installed it and then showed `1.5.2` only

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but a month ago it worked fine. I then started using svelte and now when I tried to make a react app it didn't work

Comment: @Thor84no I have update the question to show what's happening after running `npm audit fix`. Maybe it's a problem with `tar-pack`.

Comment: It worked after I did `npm uninstall create-react-app` instead of `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`! But I still get 58 vulnerabilities including 48 high

Comment: `npm uninstall create-react-app` working at all suggests you were doing this in a directory where you had installed `create-react-app`. There shouldn't be a `package.json` or a `node_modules` directory where you run `npx create-react-app`; have you made sure there wasn't?

Comment: I was running the command in the Desktop directory. But it was installed in my home directory -  `C:\Users\Name`. I just checked, yes it had a `package.json`. So it means that instead of using the latest uninstalled version, it was checking first in the directory one level up and then running it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm audit fix --force react script downgrade automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67693423/npm-audit-fix-force-react-script-downgrade-automatically)

Answer (score 7):

Short version:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

Temporary solution:

```
npx create-react-app@latest my-app
```

Now for the explanation. I think npx is running an old version of create-react-app on your computer. The first time you do `npx create-react-app`, the package is installed in the cache. npx does *not* check for newer versions if the package is cached. You can sidestep this issue by adding @latest. This forces npx to fetch the package even if it is cached.

A better solution is to clear the cache. There are other guides about how to find and remove the cache folder on windows and macos. The package `clear-npx-cache` does this.

Comment: A popular alternative to create-react-app is Vite. It's an alternative for create-react-app. To try it, type: npm init vite@latest