# vulnerability when install react-scripts

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

When I install react-scripts I get **58 vulnerabilities** (16 moderate, 40 high, 2 critical)

**My setup is :**

- Linux Debian 10
- Nodejs v14.18.1
- Npm 8.1.0
- react 17.0.2
- react-scripts 4.0.3

**deprecated packages :**

- flatten@1.0.3,
- @hapi/topo@3.1.6,
- @hapi/bourne@1.3.2,
- urix@0.1.0,
- resolve-url@0.2.1,
- querystring@0.2.1
- sane@4.1.0,
- chokidar@2.1.8,
- querystring@0.2.0,
- babel-eslint@10.1.0
- hapi/address@2.1.4,
- rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0,
- uuid@3.4.0
- hapi/joi@15.1.1,
- svgo@1.3.2,
- core-js@2.6.12

Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm audit fix --force react script downgrade automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67693423/npm-audit-fix-force-react-script-downgrade-automatically)

Answer (score 4):

If you are installing the latest version of `react-scripts`, it is very unlikely to be a problem.

You should consider moving `react-scripts` from `dependencies` to `devDependencies` in your package, if it is not there already and run `npm audit --production` instead of `npm audit`. Basically, having "vulnerabilities" in dev dependencies is most likely not an issue as they cannot be exploited.

This issue on the `create-react-app` repository explains it in details:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174

And this article from the same author explains the problem with `npm audit` in a more general context:
https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/

Comment: thank you, now it's clear for me !

Comment: Perhaps I understand react-script incorrectly, but doesn't react-script use a bundler that doesn't really care about what is and what isn't in devDependencies?

Comment: @houssam 
 > "Basically, having "vulnerabilities" in dev dependencies is most likely not an issue as they cannot be exploited." I get your point, but maybe oversimplified. From the linked article: "As any security professional will tell you, development dependencies actually are an attack vector, and perhaps one of the most dangerous ones [...]"