# 80 vulnerabilities, and every one of them can't be fixed

Tags: reactjs, npm

```
80 vulnerabilities (35 moderate, 44 high, 1 critical)
```

Is this a normal issue that you go through and fix? What do I do?

Example:

```
# npm audit report

ansi-html  *
Severity: high
Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in ansi-html - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-whgm-jr23-g3j9
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/ansi-html
  webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 4.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-html
  Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
  Depends on vulnerable versions of http-proxy-middleware
  Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server
    react-scripts  >=0.8.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
    Depends on vulnerable versions of eslint
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-watch-typeahead
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts
```

Comment: `npm audit` is a waste of time: https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/

Comment: @keul While you decide to ignore them, you may as well pull in all malicious packages saying that it doesn't matter because you only use them in development.

Comment: I don't way this is not possibile, I'm just saying _this_ audit model is broken. On a front-end env 99.8% of times you are wasting your time. There are better tools, like Snyk

Comment: am i over reacting? i dont have a mentor or anyone around to really ask. I'm solo learning this stuff. do i have to worry about this stuff right now? npm makes it seem like a huge deal, with high and critical and vulnerabilities and such.

Comment: @DrakeColeman Let say you can manually check them, not by checking them one at time, but looking at main modules.

For example: can you trust `react-scripts`? I would say "yes", so… move along to the next one.

Comment: that makes sense. the only issue is the "looking" part. i have no idea what im looking at in the console. it looks so foreign and confusing. it would help if it said stuff i have learned about. buit its some of the most random most unheard of words and descriptions it uses, these dependencies and locations.

Comment: Open pull requests with each repo to patch the vuln. Welcome to OSS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm audit fix --force react script downgrade automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67693423/npm-audit-fix-force-react-script-downgrade-automatically)