# npm vinurabillities wouldn't get fixed when i try to install babel cli

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

Hey everyone I'm trying to learn `react js` and I have a problem when I try to write html tags inside js file and based on that I'm trying to install `babel cli` here's the problem when I try to do

> npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli:

first of all I got a lot of **npm vulnerabilities** and when I try to do `npm audit fix --force` nothing changes
[here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvdAb.png).

And beside to that when I check my `package-lock-Jason` I find babel dependency
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KjPU.png).

But even my babel is there in the dependencies it still can't compile the html code.

Please any help I spent a lot of time trying to fix this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm audit fix --force react script downgrade automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67693423/npm-audit-fix-force-react-script-downgrade-automatically)

Comment: @Andrey thank u so much that works yes